# Как сохранить вложенный объект JSON в строку

Tags: java, json

Доброй ночи,
подскажите пожалуйста, как можно десериализировать разные типы (object or string) в String
Например user может быть объектом или строкой.

```
{
 "body": {
   "user": { "name", "Masha" }
}
или
{
 "body": {
   "user": "Masha"
}
```

Comment: если речь про то, чтобы упаковать данные в строку JSON, используйте JSON.stringify()

Comment: Вот несколько вариантов по JSON, в том числе по десериализации: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json